# Excel sumif conditional statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet and I'm trying to create a statement for the fees based on a drop down of regions in column I.

The formula works correctly except it is assessing the "1000" fee on any region from the drop down box in column I.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is:

If the region is "NORAM" and the total is <1000 then the fee is 1000, >1000 then payments*.01.   ($1,000.00 or 1% of total spend , whichever is greater)

```
=IFS(COUNTA(I26:I41)=0,"0",SUMIF(I26:I41,"NORAM",K26:L41)*0.01>=1000,SUMIF(I26:I41,"GAR",K26:L41)*0.01,SUMIF(I26:I41,"NORAM",K26:L41)*0.01<1000,1000)
```

[image: Payments Test]

Comment: typo.....edited to fix

Comment: does that mean your formula is now working for you, or its still a problem?

Comment: Still a problem

Comment: I do not have excel 2016 so I do not have access to IFS, however, I believe the formula will stop checking as soon as it hits a condition that is true.  Have your tried stepping through your formula?  on the formula ribbon there is an "evaluate Formula" button,  try that and watch how your formula evaluates and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: I originally did it with just an if statement but I get the same result.  I'll try your evaluate suggestion

=IF(SUMIF(I26:I41,"GAR",K26:L41)*0.01>=1000,SUMIF(I26:I41,"GAR",K26:L41)*0.01,1000)

Comment: Just in case its another typo, you are aware that you IFS formula is also doing NORAM and GAR check?  its not strickly GAR like your previous formula/

Comment: I am confused with your two formulas.  Do you mean when the region is either NORAM or GAR, and the value is greater than 1,000, you want to take the value and multiply by 0.01?  And for the value less than 1,000, just use that value directly?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just want to test for the "NORAM" region and yes you are correct in that if the value >1000 then multiply by .01 or use 1000 if the total amount of payments is less than 1000.  The problem I run into is that when I choose a different region the formula evaluates it as 0 and uses the 1000 value.